# using type returned by Type.GetType() in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

i've got a question about how is it possible (if possible :) 
to use a type reference returned by Type.GetType() to, for example, create IList of that type?

here's sample code :

```
Type customer = Type.GetType("myapp.Customer");
IList<customer> customerList = new List<customer>(); // got an error here =[
```

Thank You in Advance !

Comment: IList<T> is an interface, so you can't new it. You need to new a type which implements IList<T> such as List<T>.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(customer);
IList customerList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Of course you can't declare it as

```
IList<customer>
```

because it is not defined at compile time. But `List<T>` implements IList, so you can use this.

Comment: Yes, because it's not defined at compile time, there's not much point in using a generic List<> - you might as well use a non-generic container such as ArrayList.

Comment: Actually you should cast the result of Activator.CreateInstance to IList, since it returns an object...

Comment: @Thomas: thanks, fixed it. @Groky: It depends. Using the generic list you get runtime type checks when adding items. Or you need to assign it to a field you know (by some context) that it is of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced this problem..I realize this is an old question, but thought someone might find useful the solution i found (using net 4.0 ).
This is the setup i had:

```
public interface ISomeInterface{
     String GetEntityType{ get; }
}

public abstract class BaseClass : ISomeInterface{
     public String GetEntityType { 
          get{ return this.GetType().ToString(); }
     }
}

public class ChildA : BaseClass {  }

public class ChildB : BaseClass {  }
```

What I did was create a factory method:

```
public static dynamic GetRealType { ISomeInterface param } {
     return Activator.CreateInstance("dllname", param.GetEntityType);
}
```

Creating the object as a dynamic type was what solved it for me. I inferred the type by having a method:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T param){

     IList<T> list = somecode...
}
```

this allowed me to do a call to the method and let .net infer the type

```
public void myMethod( ISomeInterface param ) {
     dynamic value = Factory.GetRealType ( param );
     DoSomething(value);
}
```

Hope i didn't make it all confusing and it actually helps, also, sorry for the wall of text

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is provided by Stefan already.

The reason that you can not do `IList<customer>` is because you can not mix compile time and run-time types this way. 
A hint when I try to reason about something like this is: how can intellisense figure out what members it must show. In your example this can only be resolved at runtime.

The answer given  by Stefan, can be used. However I think it does not help in your underlying problem, because it does not give you intellisense. So I think you have no advantage over using just a non-generic list.

Comment: As Stefan pointed out in the comments for his answer there are still advandages, such as the generic list preventing the code from adding objects of different types to the list. You do lose intellisense though.