# How to dynamically use the PropertyType reflection attribute to create a respective typed Function<>?

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

I want to use type returned by PropertyType to create a typed function. I found this similiar
[using type returned by Type.GetType() in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914578/using-type-returned-by-type-gettype-in-c)
but this mentions how to create a list but does not mention how we can create a Func<>. Please help me out.

Pseudocode:

```
PropertyInfo inf = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("PropertyName");
Type T=inf.PropertyType;
Expression<Func<SomeClass,T>> le = GetPropertyOrFieldByName<SomeClass,T>("PropertyName");

static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> GetPropertyOrFieldByName<TSource,TResult>(string propertyOrFieldName)
{ 
ParameterExpression item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "expr");MemberExpression prop = LambdaExpression.PropertyOrField(item, propertyOrFieldName);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(prop, new ParameterExpression[] { item });
expr.Compile();
return expr;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some pseudo code with what you’d like to achieve? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: do you want to create instance of delegate or what?

Comment: Sorry if it was a bit vague...here is some code..this is what i would like to do...

PropertyInfo inf = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("PropertyName");
Type T=inf.PropertyType;
Expression<Func<SomeClass,T>> le = GetPropertyOrFieldByName<SomeClass, T>("PropertyName");

Comment: @vsj okay, but what do you plan to do with it later? you will not be able to use it normally

Comment: @Andrey..Well, I have this GetPropertyOrFieldByName Func<> which gets the that field of the class...and later using this I get values of the respective field...So basically if I know the type I can pass it to that func<>...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the `GetPropertyOrFieldByName` with the `PropertyType`, this should work:

```
PropertyInfo inf = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("PropertyName");
Type T = inf.PropertyType;

object le =
    typeof([TypeThatDeclaresMethod]).GetMethod("GetPropertyOrFieldByName")
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass), T)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { "PropertyName" });
```

Assuming that the `GetPropertyOrFieldByName` method is a public static method.

Comment: Hi I tried to use the above method but get an null reference exception...I want to get a list from the method and  TypeThatDeclaresMethod means the class that has the method or return type?.sorry I am new to reflection..so I have added the GetPropertyOrFieldByName to the code above in the question..please help me out

Comment: `[TypeThatDeclaresMethod]` is the name of the class that has the method. So if you have a class called `Program` that contains `GetPropertyOrFieldByName`, than your call would be: `typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetPropertyOrFieldByName")`.

Comment: Hi,Thanks..actually I didnt have the method public so it returned null now I have it an Object variable that has the exression value so I convert it tostring  so how do I  use this string variable as a Expression ?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I don't understand what you'd like to know.

Comment: Well I have a string now that has the expression value to be evaluated..like expr=>expr.FieldName so I want to use this string as Linq.Expression or any other way to query the DB.

Comment: Perhaps you could start a new thread here at SO. Please describe as clearly as possible what your intent is. There clearer the better.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `MakeGenericType(new Type[] { SomeClass, T })`.

**EDIT** More detail:

```
Type T2 = typeof(Excpression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { SomeClass, T }));
... Activator.CreateInstance(T2);
```

,

Answer (score 1):

You can create the expression tree, but you can't declare its type in the code. Where you've got this:

```
Expression<Func<SomeClass,T>> le = ...
```

`T` has to be known at *compile time* (or be a type parameter). Instead, your `T` is a *variable* whose value is only known at *execution time*.

Now, the next question is whether you really need that anyway - or in what *way* you need it. What are you trying to do with the expression? Could you just use the nongeneric `Expression` class instead as the variable type?

If you genuinely want an expression tree, you don't need to worry about `MakeGenericType` etc - use the `Expression.Property` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Type parameter = ...;
Type result = ...;
Type your_type = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] {parameter, result});
```