# How to call a generic method using a type returned from a different method?

Tags: c#

I have two types Person and Organisation both inheriting from `IContact`.

I have a method that returns one of these types based on some logic

```
private Type GetPersonOrOrganisation(string some variable)
{
   either returns Person or Organisation type
}
```

I have a method which queries the database for Persons or Orgs:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Query<T>(this IUow uow) where T : IContact
        {
            return uow.Query<T>();
        }
```

My question is how can I use the Type returned from `GetPersonOrOrganisation` to call query.

So say:

```
var contactType = GetPersonOrOrganisation(string some variable);

 var contact = Query<contactType>();
```

where contactType will be either Person or Organisation.

Well obviously that won't compile and that's my question. How to make the query on the right type from the database based on what is returned from `GetPersonOrOrganisation`.

Comment: Any reason why there is no IContact GetPersonOrOrganisation(string some variable)?

Comment: Yes, I need the type to call query because the query method requires the type no an actual object of that type.

Answer (score 2):

Moving between `Type` and generics is a major pain; the only answer without refactoring is: reflection; something like:

```
var method = typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("Query").MakeGenericMethod(contactType);
// this is to getch your Query<T>(this IUow) method

var contact = (IContact)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { uow });
```

which is pretty horrible. If possible, I would suggest rewriting your `Query<T>` method as a `Query(Type type)` method (returning `IContact`), which still trivially allows a generic `Query<T>` helper method for the existing code, via `return (T) Query(typeof(T));`. The reverse is not the case, however.

If you were passing an instance of type `T` *into* the method, there are some tricks you can do to simplfiy this, by using `dynamic` to perform the type/generics/method resolution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.
However, what you are trying to accomplish actually?

Consider using ArrayList or List instead. As modification about which type to be returned in Query, you can tweak the method like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Query<T>(this IUow uow, Type returnType) where T : IContact
{
  if(returnType is IContact) // code here
}
```

That is quick code which maybe has error.

This stackoverflow link already has discussion about this:
[using type returned by Type.GetType() in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914578/using-type-returned-by-type-gettype-in-c-sharp)