# Generics of unknown type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm creating a settings class like so:

```
class Setting<T> {...}
```

I am storing all the settings in a tree like so:

```
class SettingsNode {
    public Setting<> setting;
    public Setting<> child;
    public Setting<> sibling;
}
```

This obviously doesn't compile because of the `<>`. I can have multiple types (`Setting<int>`, `Setting<string>`, etc) so I don't know how to create the SettingsNode.

So I changed it to:

```
class SettingsNode {
    public object setting;
    public object child;
    public object sibling;
}
```

But am having trouble with casting to the right type:

```
// Create a setting from a type name as text
SettingsNode tmp = new SettingsNode();

Type genericType = typeof(Setting<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { Type.GetType("System.Int32") };
Type cType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
tmp.setting = Activator.CreateInstance(cType);

// Here's where I have a problem
Type baseType = typeArgs[0];
((Setting<baseType>)(tmp.setting)).SomeFunction();
```

The error on that last line is:

> The type or namespace name 'baseType' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you just try SettingsNode<T1,T2,T3,T4..>. Just Curious since dynamic is the safest implementation

Comment: @JoachimGotzes Sorry, I don't remember. It's been over 3 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is you can go ahead with [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) keyword:

```
class SettingsNode
{
    public dynamic setting;
    public dynamic child;
    public dynamic sibling;
}
```

So you can do like this:

```
SettingsNode tmp = new SettingsNode();
tmp.setting = new Setting<int>();

tmp.setting.SomeFunction()
```

Without need using reflection

Comment: Child and sibling may not be of type T.

Comment: Was pulled off this project for a while. Finally getting back to it. `dynamic` is working great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have:

```
class SettingsNode<T> {
    public Setting<T> setting;
    public Setting<T> child;
    public Setting<T> sibling;
}
```

Comment: because `T` has to be the same for the entire tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go down that route make an abstract non-generic base class `abstract class Setting` and a generic `Setting<T> : Setting`. Define all common methods in non-generic one using `object` instead of a `T` and use the generic one just as an adapter which calls `super`'s methods/properties and does casting object<=>T in each method/property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think generics are the right tool for this. Generics are a *compile-time tool*: If the generic type is not known at compile time, there is no advantage over a non-generic type.

So, unless you plan to *explicitly* use `Setting<Int32>` and `Setting<String>`  in your code, there is just no point in using generics here, and you might as well stick with `Setting`.

Answer (score 0):

Generics cannot do that.
The whole point of generics is to specify the type parameter within the type system – at compile time.
You're trying to make those fields have no known type.

Instead, you should make the generic class inherit from a non-generic `SettingsBase` base class (or interface), and make the fields of that type.
Calling code can cast them back to the actual generic types.

Comment: I originally had it that way: SettingsBase -> SettingsInt, SettingsString, etc. I was hoping generics would simplify things.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: That's not what I meant.  I mean `public class Settings<T> : SettingsBase`.

Answer (score 0):

If `Setting<T>` defines a method:

```
public T Transform(T value);
```

...and you could define a field of type `Setting<?>`, then what type of parameter would `Transform` accept? `object` is the only type common to all possible `T`. So you lose all type safety. And what type of parameter would `Transform` return? Again, `object`, so you have to cast everything.

You should view each generic class instance as a different type: manually copying your `Setting<T>` class as `SettingOfInt32` and replacing all `T` by `Int32`, is simply automated by the generic syntax `Setting<Int32>`. So, instead of thinking `Setting<Int32>` and `Setting<String>` are both `Setting<T>`, you should think that you have `SettingOfInt32` and `SettingOfString` that are both derived from `Object`.

Imagine you want to be able to put objects of type `SettingOfInt32` and `SettingOfString` in a field, what type must the field have? Of course, a type that is common to both, such as `object`. Now you might realize that if you want to call any method that exists in both `SettingOfInt32` and `SettingOfString`, you should move that method to a common base class, e.g. `Setting`. Then your field's type must be `Setting` and all is well.

```
public class Setting<T> : Setting { }

public abstract class Setting { }
```

This also forces you to deal with things like the `Transform` example above. Do you include it in the common base class? Maybe, maybe not. What types do you use instead of `T`? Maybe `object`, maybe something else. Do you do explicit type checking? Possibly...

Answer (score 0):

As stated by , I do not think generics should be used for this scenario.
If you want / need to stick to it, you could try using a class with multiple generics.

```
public class SettingsNode<TSetting, TChild, TSibbling>
{
    public Setting<TSetting> Setting { get; set; }
    public Setting<TChild> Child { get; set; }
    public Setting<TSibbling> Sibling { get; set; }
}

public class Setting<T>
{
    public T Value;
}

SettingsNode<String, int, int> node = new SettingsNode<string, int, int>();
node.Sibling = new Setting<int>();
node.Setting = new Setting<string>();
node.Child = new Setting<int>();
```

[Here's a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914578/using-type-returned-by-type-gettype-in-c-sharp/8903800#8903800) I took once when I did not know what type to expect. This involves the usage of dynamic keyword, so requires c# 4.0+