# How to get base type for the particular type

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am working on a C# code analyzer and use Roslyn (.NET Compiler API).

And I would like to check, that a particular type is inherited from a base class type.

For example, let's assume we have a hierarchy of custom classes:

`TypeA -> TypeB -> TypeC -> TypeD`

Where `TypeA` is parent class for `TypeB`, `TypeB` is parent for `TypeC` and `TypeC` is parent for `TypeD`.

I created a method:

```
    bool InheritsFrom(ITypeSymbol symbol, string expectedParentTypeName)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (symbol.ToString().Equals(expectedParentTypeName))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (symbol.BaseType != null)
            {
                symbol = symbol.BaseType;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

`symbol` contains the type, that should be checked. But this approach does not work. Code does not get the parent type for the symbol.

`symbol.BaseType` returns the same class type twice and then (on the next iteration) I get `symbol.BaseType` equal to `null`.

`expectedParentTypeName` contains fully qualified type name: for example `some.namespace.blablabla.TypeC`

How can I solve this task?

---

**Update**

As I noted above, let's assume we have a hierarchy:

`TypeA -> TypeB -> TypeC -> TypeD`

Upon analysis I get a property with type `TypeD` and I want to check, that it is inherited from `TypeB`

---

**Update #2**

`TypeA -> TypeB -> TypeC -> TypeD` types **are not existing yet** when I write my code analyser. So, I can't use typeof and other stuff for these types.

They will exist only in context the analyzer will work in.

My analyzer gets a part of the source code, recognizes it as a type name and  I want to check, that this recognized type name is inherited from another custom type, imported from a **custom** nuget package.

All I have - I have source code to analyze and names of those custom types in class, property, field, etc declarations.

---

**Update #3**

For the following code:

```
SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context; // is already initialized 

PropertyDeclarationSyntax propertyDeclaration = (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration = (ClassDeclarationSyntax) propertyDeclaration.Parent;

TypeInfo propertyTypeInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(propertyDeclaration);

TypeInfo classTypeInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(classDeclaration);
```

`propertyTypeInfo` and `classTypeInfo` do not contain any information inside.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `ITypeSymbol.BaseType` is exactly that you need to retrieve the base type. `BaseType` can be null if your type is `System.Object`, interface or pointer type, also if you have a couple of troubles with semantic logic in your `Compilation` it can be a error type, which mean you miss something reference and Roslyn cannot corectly resolve a types. In other case `symbol.BaseType` should work very well by default. So I sugges you to check your symbol and check diagnostics in `Compilation`
2. `ITypeSymbol.ToString()` will return string that would be constructed by [CSharpErrorMessageFormat](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/SymbolDisplay/SymbolDisplayFormat.cs,ded72a15c2166272), which has FQN type style that is enough for your question. If you would a more, you can pass a custom `SymbolDisplayFormat` to `ToDisplayString`
3. For declaration nodes `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo` will returns the null `TypeSymbol` and `ConvertedSymbol` by design, instead of this you should use `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol`

   ```cs
   var propertyTypeSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(propertyDeclaration) as ITypeSymbol;
   var classTypeSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration) as ITypeSymbol;
   ```

   P.S. be carefull, to use `GetDeclaredSymbol` for some special declaration nodes: for example `FieldDeclarationSyntax`)

Comment: I think I figured out, how to solve this task. Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Just `is`   ?

```
if(DerivedType is BaseType)
{
    //Party time
}
```

Comment: thank you for assistance, Dave. But I operate not with system types, but with `ITypeSymbol` instances of custom (not-standard) C# classes. I am not sure that this approach is applicable in this case.

Answer (score -1):

There are ways (referred to in other stack questions) to create an object from a typename at runtime. (There are some useful code snippets in here: [using type returned by Type.GetType() in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914578/using-type-returned-by-type-gettype-in-c-sharp))

You could then get an object of your `symbol` and check if it is of that type passed in.

```
if (symbolObject is typeClassWorkedOutAbove)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: thank you. Roslyn provides mechanisms to operate with types and other parts of the syntax tree without making instances of processing classes. Also note that processing type may be heavy/complex and most probably will require additional objects to be passed to its constructor, etc.